# Cant view provision files

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I'm working in an application and until yesterday I was able to build it without any problem. But now I can't select provision files under the build settings in the targets. It shows provision files as general files given in this image. How can I solve it?[image]

Comment: What is the exact error given when you try to build/run?

Comment: Its not about errors but the build wont work